# HttpError 403 (forbidden) when accessing Google Drive using PyDrive

Tags: google-drive-api, pydrive

I try to perform some operations on my Google Drive using PyDrive (and service account). This account has the right scope set in *admin.google.com* and in Dev's Console I've turned on both Drive API and Drive SDK.

Here's the code snippet:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        service_account_name, #...@developer.gserviceaccount.com
        key, # from file
        scope, # https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
        sub='...' # user
)
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = credentials
gauth.Authorize()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello.txt'})
file1.Upload()
```

However, I get the following error: `pydrive.files.ApiRequestError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json returned "Forbidden">`

Why, oh why?

PS. Using the credentials provided (with a bit different scope) I can succesfully access spreadsheets (with `gspread` library).

Comment: The scope strings must match exactly between your code and the Admin Console, including trailing slashes, etc. Can you check that they match?

Comment: Yes, they do match.
I assume I don't provide here also all other scopes I've been granted, right?

Comment: Can you also check that Drive Apps are allowed on the domain? ("Allow users to install Google Drive apps").